# Python deleting not interpreted chars by UTF8 Encode from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8, io, character-encoding

As you can see in picture below, there are some chars which is not interpreted in UTF8 encoding (opened with notepad++). And I want to clear them by just deleting them in python 3. I got the lines with code:

```
hdl = open(r'C:\Users\BerkayS\Desktop\testfile.txt', 'r')
lines=f.readlines()
```

How can I delete these chars (OR if we cannot delete we can swap them with space as secondary option)

[image]

Comment: depending on what those char's actually are, you might be able to call `str.strip()` on them which would normally strip off extra whitespace. It's hard to tell whether this would actually work since you dont know what kind of chars they are, but probably worth a try.

Comment: You didn't specify an encoding when you opened that file, so the current locale's encoding is used, and that's probably _not_ UTF-8 on a Windows machine, unless you've configured it that way. See [the `open` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) for details. If you are _certain_ that the file actually _is_  UTF-8 then you should open it as UTF-8. Otherwise, try to find out what the encoding is so you can process this data properly.